# How to make a not bootable counter when refreshing the web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a counter remains dynamic and non-bootable when updating
web page, 
here is my code the problem is that when I refresh the page the counter(setTimeout) will count again from zero to 5 I want it to count from the last value before
the refresh

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("tm").style.display='block'}, 
5000);

</script> 
<body>

<form id="customer" action="/htmlvalidation" method="post">
<div>
    <label>Time</label>
    <input id="tm" type="text" style="display: none;"/>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit">Add Customer</button>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you

Comment: What does "non-bootable" mean? And, what (in the code you've supplied) has anything to do with your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: `document.cookie` might be useful here.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to manually store the counter value in the client's browser; by default, browsers will not retain any of a webpage's state when it is closed (or refreshed). For example, you may use the [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
const STORAGE_KEY = 'counter';
const TARGET_ELEMENT_ID = 'counter-div';
const INTERVAL = 1000;
const INC = 1;

// Notice the '+' below to make sure val is a number.
let val = +localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) || 0; 

document.getElementById(TARGET_ELEMENT_ID).innerHTML = val;

setInterval(() => {
  val += INC;
  localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, val);
  document.getElementById(TARGET_ELEMENT_ID).innerHTML = val;
}, INTERVAL);
```

[Here is a working example on codepen](https://codepen.io/roque/pen/YaRKzJ) (it seems stackoverflow's snippets do not support localStorage).

(I didn't use your snippet because I wasn't sure what you were trying to do).

Answer (score 1):

You could store the last timer iteration using localStorage before the user closes or navigates away from the tab, and resume when needed.

[More about localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)